# Difficulty toggling media query using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[Link to site](http://cluster4.website-staging.uk/simplyfloors.co.uk/)

I'm trying to format the menu on the above site, when it's in sticky mode (i.e. scrolled down), because at certain widths the Request a Quote button is obscured by the screen. I'm using Javascript to action the change only when the screen is scrolled down, and an additional CSS class to move the menu. Unfortunately it's not working - while I can move the menu using just CSS applied directly to the existing class, trying to tie this in with JS to make it scroll specific doesn't any effect.

Is anyone able to tell me where I'm going wrong please?

Thank you in advance.

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$ = jQuery;
$(function() {
    //caches a jQuery object containing the header element
    var header = $(".header-widget");
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 20) {
            $(".header-widget").addClass("header-widget-shortheader");
            $(".second-header-widget").addClass("second-header-widget-shortheader");
            $(".navbar .nav").addClass(".stickyheader-midscreen-cta-fix");

        } else {
            $(".header-widget").removeClass("header-widget-shortheader");
            $(".second-header-widget").removeClass(".second-header-widget-shortheader");
            $(".navbar .nav").removeClass(".stickyheader-midscreen-cta-fix");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
/* -----Moves menu to avoid cutting off CTA button with sticky header on mid-sized screen (toggle with JS in 'Header & Footer')----- */
@media screen and (min-width: 980px) and (max-width: 1189px) {
.stickyheader-midscreen-cta-fix {
  margin: 40px 22% 0 0;
  float: right;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is at line 6:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
```

(did not actually call the function on scroll)

Solution:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
```

For your design problem, you can decrease the width of the headers on certain screen sizes by adding the below code at the end of file: `/wp-content/themes/customizr-child/style.css`

```
@media screen 
and (max-width:1200px)
and (min-width: 980px) {
  .sticky-enabled .navbar-wrapper {
    margin-left: 0;
  }  
  .sticky-enabled .navbar-wrapper a {
    padding-right: 7px!important;
    padding-left: 7px!important;
  }
}
```

Comment: That didn't work either, I'm afraid. I should add that the script works for toggling the `header-widget-shortheader` and `second-header-widget-shortheader` classes. I wonder whether line 5 `var header = $(".header-widget");` might be the problem because the one class change that doesn't work is `.navbar .nav`, if that makes sense?

Comment: @FishOnABicycle open your developer console(F2) and add the 'debugger' in your code.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b9KifHCZ0QM
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp

Comment: Apologies, I'd turned it off yesterday and forgot to turn it on again before asking the question. It's now on again.

Comment: Having started watching the video I now realise WP_DEBUG being on isn't what you meant. I'm looking at the video and trying to follow it but must confess I'm struggling a bit - any further help solving the issue would be gratefully received. Thanks.

Comment: @FishOnABicycle One moment please

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: On second thoughts, it looks like it is! Just having a play, but looks like this could be the answer...

Comment: Marian, thank you - you've cracked it. Much appreciated - I'll post what I ended up with as a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Marian07 for the support. This is where I ended up:

```
/* -----Fixes menu CTA button being cut off by mid size screens----- */

@media screen and (min-width: 980px) and (max-width:1084px) {
.sticky-enabled .navbar-wrapper {
    margin-left: 0;
  }  
.sticky-enabled .navbar-wrapper a {
    padding-right: 9px!important;
    padding-left: 8px!important;
    font-size: 95% !important;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1085px) and (max-width:1200px) {
  .sticky-enabled .navbar-wrapper {
    margin-left: 0;
  }  
  .sticky-enabled .navbar-wrapper a {
    padding-right: 3px!important;
    padding-left: 25px!important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove . use only class name

```
$(".navbar .nav").addClass(".stickyheader-midscreen-cta-fix");
```

replace

```
$(".navbar .nav").addClass("stickyheader-midscreen-cta-fix");

$(".navbar .nav").removeClass(".stickyheader-midscreen-cta-fix");
```

replace

```
$(".navbar .nav").removeClass("stickyheader-midscreen-cta-fix");
```

Comment: Thank you, that was part of the problem I can see, but even with that correction the menu is still not moving on scroll for 980-1189px screens?